# Get RegEx Group by Index

Tags: java, regex, json

I've made a class in Java to create an object and one of my static methods converts some JSON to the object (I have a JavaScript version so it makes for easy transference).

A sample bit of the JSON is:

```
{"header": ["H1","H2","H3"], "cells": [["R1C1","R1C2","R1C3"],["Row 2, Column 1","Row 2, C2","R2 - C2"]]}
```

In my method, I'm not using any JSON package because as far as I know, it would require me having to download one, so I've been using RegEx to extract the data.

Method:

```
public static Table jsonToTable(String json) {
    Pattern h = Pattern.compile("\"header\": \[((?:\" *[^\"]+ *\",?)+)]");
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\"cells\": \[((\[(?:(?:\" *[^\"]+ *\",?)+)],?)+)]");

    Matcher hm = h.matcher(json);
    Matcher rm = r.matcher(json);

    ArrayList<String> header = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(hm.group(0).split(",")));
    String[] _rows = rm.group(0).split(",");
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    for (String row : _rows) {
        row = row.replace("[","");
        row = row.replace("]","");
        rows.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(row.split(","))));
    }
    Table t = new Table(header);
    for (ArrayList<String> row : rows) {
        t.addRow(row);
    }
    return t;
}
```

With this method, I get a Runtime error whenever I use it. I get no description at all so I'm not 100% certain on what is causing the errors. I am just assuming the groups.

With the patterns however, how I have written them above, the opening `[` braces have been escaped though ideone.com compiler doesn't like that so it's possible that's the problem.

Is anyone able to tell me what is causing the Runtime error? I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to parse JSON via regular expressions. There are plenty of ready libraries available to do so.

Comment: You can't build regex which will be good parser (at least not in Java where regex doesn't support recursion). For instance in your `[^\"]+` you are assuming that String content can't have `"` inside, but that is not true. We can place `"` if we escape it properly. Even if you are writing regex for your own specific class it is still better to use proper parser instead of reinventing one.

Comment: @Pshemo I know that. I work on perfecting it after I get the basics working.

Comment: OK you are free man with right to make your own mistakes. Lets hope you will not need to change this regex to often because that would be maintaining hell with high risk to introduce more problems than you would solve.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `group()` method of a `Matcher` object if first you don't have a match. You should use this method inside blocks like:

```
 while(matcher.find()){ //this if you want to match globally
      String matched = matcher.group();
 }
```

or

```
 if(matcher.find()){ //this if you want just the first match
      String matched = matcher.group();
 }
```